# $mysqli->escape_string - can it be used without specifying exact field name

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I have code that generalizes building the SQL string to insert a record into a table by (1) setting the 'name' of the form element to be the same as the table column to which it corresponds, and (2) building an array of field name => value pairs. I do it like this:

```
$fldArray = array();
foreach($_POST as $field => $value) {
    $fldArray[$field] = $value; //create a field => value array
}
```

This allows me to  build the SQL statement easily like this:

```
    $visit_SQL = "INSERT INTO visits (";
        foreach ($fldArray as $key => $value) {
                 $flds .= ($key) . ", " ; // sets up all the field names.
```

I then do something similar to generate the 'VALUES' part of the SQL statement. I then need only to add the provider_id info

```
 $visit_SQL = $visit_SQL . "provider_id, " . $flds . ") VALUES (" . $user_ID . ", " . $vals . ")";
```

The reason I go about it this way is that there are a large number of Yes/No checkboxes on the form so it saves typing errors etc.

This works well except for two text inputs that require "$mysqli->escape_string(['field_name']) to deal with apostrophes etc. before inserting into the database.
I proved that the following works for explicit field names,

```
 $test = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['visit_notes']);  

  print_r($test) ;
```

However, I cannot generalize it into this statement (from above):

```
   foreach($_POST as $field => $mysqli->escape_string($_POST[$value])) {
    $fldArray[$field] = $value; 
    }
```

I'd appreciate knowing if I have a syntax error or if what I'm seeking is not possible.
Thanks in advance for any helpful responses.

Comment: `foreach($_POST as $field => $value) {
    $fldArray[$field] = $mysqli->escape_string($value); 
    }` - However, a better way to do this is to drop `escape_string()` **_ENTIRELY_** and using prepared statements with binded parameters.

Comment: Don't escape. Bind parameters instead!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I've corrected my syntax per your input.  Thanks very much.  I will explore binding parms as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put the function call in the `foreach` header, you do it in the body.

```
foreach($_POST as $field => $value) {
    $fldArray[$field] = $mysqli->escape_string($value); 
}
```